# Error attempting Sideload/install of Desktop Bridge App - The system cannot find the file specified 0x80070002

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I am hitting an error when attempting to sideload/install (for QA test purposes) the .appxbundle built for my app with the Windows Application Packaging Project (i.e. Desktop Bridge within Visual Studio). The error is...

App installation failed with error message: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)

In troubleshooting this issue I have tried:

- Rebooting the PC then retrying the install (hoping any errant file locks would be released by a reboot)
- Installing the new appxbundle as an UPDATE (to an existing install)
- Installing the new appxbundle as a brand NEW install (after uninstalling the app)
- I even attempted sideload/install of an EARLIER version appxbundle that installed in the past without error and now that appxbundle also fails with the same error.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: One other piece of information that just came to mind...Microsoft is currently working on an MS Store issue related to publishing my app to the Store. They are actively working on the issue/support-case today. It is possible that this error relates to something MS is doing on their side. If the issue goes away when MS completes work on the Store support-case, I will update this post.

Comment: All appxbundles now install without error. As best I can tell it must have been something that MS was doing on their side. I presume that early in the install process, the app identity and/or cert is checked over the internet against MS servers and that part was off-line/not-available temporarily while they worked on my case.

Comment: My recommendation to the MS team on this is to improve the error messaging for this exception. If my assumptions above are correct this same error would occur when sideloading on a machine that is has no internet connection. A more descriptive error message would have saved me some time on this. Note: I performed an internet search for the error message I received and found very little information (which is why I posted this question).

Answer (score 0):

All appxbundles now are installing without error (with no changes at all to them). As best I can tell it must have been something that MS was doing on their side. I presume that early in the install process, the app identity and/or security certificate is checked over the internet against MS servers and that part was off-line/not-available temporarily while they worked on my case. If you hit the same error as me, it could be because your machine has no internet connection (or something on the MS side is off-line temporarily).